# ./configure Permission denied - Compiling Qt

Tags: c++, permissions, qt

I'm new to Linux/Rasperry Pi and I was following [this tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/Native_Build_of_Qt_5.4.1_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) to create a native build of Qt. I got up to the `./configure` step. But this gives me the error:

> bash: ./configure Permission denied

I think it has something to do that I want to run the configuration from a USB drive (as instructed in the tutorial). How can I get this to work?

Comment: I had the exact same problem, following the same tutorial! Can you tell me how your usb drive is formatted? If it is not formatted in ext3/ext4, then try doing so

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how [unix modes and permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)), used on POSIX operating systems such as GNU/Linux and OSX work, otherwise your life is going to be full of awkward problems like this.  There are already [lots](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) and [lots](http://www.comentum.com/unix-osx-permissions.html) of introductions online, I will not bother regurgitating them.

However, I'll give an example of applying the concepts in this case.  First, you need to know some id numbers for your current user:

```
id $(whoami)
```

Will give you your `uid`, `gid`, and a list of groups whose permissions you can use.

`./configure` is a file.  To get the modes and permissions set on it:

```
stat ./configure
```

It's in the first line labelled "Access:" (there are two), and will be something like `0755/drwxr-xr-x`.  All of those links from above explain how to decipher that.  See also `man stat`.

You need to change the ownership on the whole directory tree, since you are going to be building software in it.  For that you can use the `-R` (recursive) switch to `chown` (see also `man chown`), but you need privileges to do so, via `sudo`.  Presuming you are in the same directory as the `configure` file, and you are user `pi`:

```
sudo chown -R pi.pi .
```

You could of course just do `sudo ./configure` and proceed that way, but this way you are playing safe.  *On the other hand*, if you are intending to do a system wide install, you will need to do so at some point (`sudo make install`).

---

Note that this is not necessarily an *ownership* problem, which will be obvious when you examine the files in question; it can also be purely *mode* related.  To execute a file, it needs to be set as executable (adds 1 to the mode, e.g., 7 is read/write/execute, 6 is read/write, 5 is read/execute, 4 is just read).  It would be a bit bizarre in this case, but certainly not impossible depending on how the source archive was unpacked and the USB drive mounted.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer but `sudo ./configure ` was the first thing I tried. This gives me **sudo ./configure: command not found:**

Comment: `stat ./configure` tells me I have the permission 0644. Right click on the file say "Execute: Nobody" and I can't seem to change it

Comment: Looks like it's not executable, which is kinda weird.  I've added a last paragraph about this.   I suggest you ask a more detailed version of this question on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), since the brand of hardware is really irrelevant here.  By "more detailed", I mean including the fact that you used `sudo`, that `./configure` has ended up 644, and exactly how the USB stick was mounted (if it was automounted and use a default Raspbian configuration, say, "automounted by [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE)").

Comment: I should rephrase that.  You want to find out exactly *why* `.configure` might end up non-executable.  I don't think they would ship the package that way, and there may be other files with the wrong mode which will cause other problems.  Since the instructions included using `mount --bind`, check and see if the mode/permissions are identical in both places.

Comment: Ok I will probably post a Question on the Unix & Linux site. FYI, I mounted the USB exactly how it was described in the linked tutorial. Also, afaik all the files in the mounted folder are set to be non-executable for some reason

Comment: There's a good chance that `.configure` is the only one that counts (this is often the case, but Qt is a big complex build), so you could try using `chmod` on that and just crossing your fingers.  Even if the build flunks eventually because of some similar issue, you should be able to correct that and then continue with the `make` without having to do everything over again.

Comment: I also tried that (sudo chmod -x configure) but after it I still have the same "Execute: Nobody" permission. There was no error when running the chmod command... Quite strange. I think I'll post a new question on Unix & Linux tomorrow describing all my steps